# cursor pointer not working at chrome,but work at safari and firefox

Tags: css

css:

```
         .load_more{
                width:100%;
                height: 44px;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #5dc7d0;
                border:none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-family: $base-font;
                font-size: 18px;
                margin-top: 22px;
                cursor: pointer
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[ask]** and **[mcve]**

Comment: It is working as expected. Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/b1uyt9tu/2/). If possible please share your html code

Answer (score -2):

ur code is working fine there might be some other css overwriting ur css, u should inspect elemnt and check that, also check below code and see if it works for u

```css
.load_more{
  width:100%;
  height: 44px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5dc7d0;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: $base-font;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
.load_more, .load_more a{
  cursor: pointer!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="load_more">
  im having some <a href="#">link</a> here
</div>
```